# search in pandas series des not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, one of the columns is "name" of type string.
I'm trying to find out if a name appears in that column.

This happens:

```
In  [1]: print specific_name in df['name']
Out [1]: False
In  [2]: print specific_name in df['name'].tolist()
Out [2]: True
```

Why do I have to turn it into a list?

Comment: because it's ambiguous, what if specfic_name is in only 1 row in the series should this be true? you should do `df[df['name'] == specfic_name]` or `df['name'].isin([specific_name[)` note I had to turn your string into a list with a single string

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. What do I do if I want all the rows that have a name that is in a list called "specific names"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is an ambiguous call because you haven't specified under what conditions it should evaluate to `True`.

To filter out rows that match your string do this:

```
df[df['name'] == specific_name]
```

or

```
df[df['name'].isin([specific_name])]
```

Note I have to put your string into a list as it has to be an iterable object

If we try what you attempted:

```
In [122]:

'hello' in df['name']
Out[122]:
False
```

This is because it is ambiguous.

```
In [119]:

df[df['name']=='hello']
Out[119]:
    name
0  hello
In [121]:

df[df['name'].isin(['hello'])]
Out[121]:
    name
0  hello
```

To do a match on a list use `isin`:

```
In [123]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['hello','world','python']})
df
Out[123]:
     name
0   hello
1   world
2  python

In [126]:

specifc_names = ['hello', 'world']
df[df['name'].isin(specifc_names)]
Out[126]:
    name
0  hello
1  world
```

We can also use multiple boolean criteria but remember to use the array operators and you need to put braces around the conditions due to operator precedence:

```
In [127]:

df[(df['name'] == 'hello') | (df['name']=='world')]
Out[127]:
    name
0  hello
1  world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : `(df.name == 'Name').sum() > 0`

It will return True if the name 'Name' is in the column.